# How to write a long equation without it going over the margin?

Tags: equations, align, split

This is my LaTeX code

I'm using these packages

```
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,mathrsfs}
```

And the code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,mathrsfs}

 \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
 \frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{\substack{n = 1 \\ m = 1}} ^ {N_ { m }, N_{ m }} 
  \qty( \frac{\pi^{2}n^{ 2 }}{s _ { f } ^ { 2 } } + \frac{\pi ^ { 2 } m ^2} 
  { L ^ { 2 } } - \tilde { E } )  \underbrace {\int\limits_0^L \qty( \cos 
 \frac { \pi \qty( m ^ { \prime } - m ) x }{ L } - \cos \frac{\pi\qty( m ^ { 
\prime } + m ) z}{ L }) V(s,z) \dd{z} }_{I_1} \, \times \\
\underbrace {\int\limits_0^{s_f} \qty(\cos \f{\pi(n^\prime -n)s}{s_f} - \cos 
\frac{ \pi \qty( n^\prime + n ) s } { s _ { f } }) \dd{s}}_{I^\prime_1} 
\cdot  C_{n,m}  + \frac { 1 } { 4 } \sum\limits_{\substack{ n =1 \\ m = 1 }} 
^ { N _ { n }, N _ { m } } \int\limits _ { 0 } ^ { s _ { f } } \qty(  \cos 
\frac { \pi \left( n ^ { \prime } - n \right) s } { s _ { f } } - \cos \frac 
{ \pi \left( n ^ { \prime } + n \right) s } { s _ { f } } )\dd{s} \times \\
\int _ { 0 } ^ { L } \left[ \cos \frac { \pi \left( m ^ { \prime } - m 
\right) x } { L } - \cos \frac { \pi \left( m ^ { \prime } + m \right) z } { 
 L }  \right] V (s,z) \dd{z}\cdot C_{n,m}=0
 \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}
 \end{document}
```

and I get this

[image]

I want that my equation doesn't break in the margins.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is `\qty`? Please post a full compilable code.

Comment: It's the same \left(..... \right), but with a  \usepackage{physics}

Comment: What is `\f`? Your code does not compile.

Comment: don't make it hard for people to help you,  please make the example complete from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` in particular you ask that it fits the margins without saying what size your page is..

Comment: why do you have `\limits` everywhere and why `^{\prime}` instead of `'` ?

Comment: So it looks better

Comment: What is `\dd`? Please, define it.

Comment: I already fixed all the errors, so it compiles. \dd is an expression within of the physics package to write dz. you can see the overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/1799449214ktwmkttdfvhg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, given that you introduce the two abbreviations, I suspect that you will agree with me that this equation is a bit bulky. I'd hence like to argue that the readers, and even after some months you yourself, will appreciate if you disentangle things a bit, which at the same time solves the issue.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{4}&\sum\limits_{\substack{n = 1 \\ m = 1}} ^ {N_ { m }, N_{ m }} 
  \qty( \frac{\pi^{2}n^{ 2 }}{s _ { f } ^ { 2 } } + \frac{\pi ^ { 2 } m ^2} 
  { L ^ { 2 } } - \tilde { E } ) I_1
 \times I^\prime_1
 \cdot  C_{n,m}  \notag \\
+ \frac {1}{4}& \sum\limits_{\substack{ n =1 \\ m = 1 }} 
^ { N _ { n }, N _ { m } } \int\limits _ { 0 } ^ { s _ { f } } \qty(  \cos 
\frac { \pi \left( n ^ { \prime } - n \right) s } { s _ { f } } - \cos \frac 
{ \pi \left( n ^ { \prime } + n \right) s } { s _ { f } } )\dd{s} & \notag \\
 &\times \int _ { 0 } ^ { L } \left[ \cos \frac { \pi \left( m ^ { \prime } - m 
\right) x } { L } - \cos \frac { \pi \left( m ^ { \prime } + m \right) z } { 
 L }  \right] V (s,z) \dd{z}\cdot C_{n,m} =0\;,
\end{align}
where
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
  I_1&=\int\limits_0^L \qty( \cos 
 \frac { \pi \qty( m ^ { \prime } - m ) x }{ L } - \cos \frac{\pi\qty( m ^ { 
\prime } + m ) z}{ L }) V(s,z) \dd{z}\;, \\
 I^\prime_1&=\int\limits_0^{s_f} \qty(\cos f{\pi(n^\prime -n)s}{s_f} - \cos 
\frac{ \pi \qty( n^\prime + n ) s } { s _ { f } }) \dd{s}\;.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're a good designer, it looks better,  thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use the `medsize` environment from `nccmath`, and alsp a variant  with the `multlined` environment, instead of `aligned`. Note  you don't have to load `latexsym`: its symbols are found in `amssymb`, and it's simpler to type `'` rather than `^{\prime}`. For the integral with limits, you simply can pass `limits` as an option to `amsmath`.

```
    \documentclass[intlimits]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathrsfs}

    \begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{medsize}
     \begin{aligned}
 \frac{1}{4}\sum_{\substack{n = 1 \\ m = 1}}^{N_{m}, N _{m}}
 \qty(\frac{\pi^{2} n^{2}}{ s_{f}^{2}} + \frac{\pi^{2} m^{2} } {L^{2}} - \tilde{ E })
 \underbrace {\int_0^L \qty( \cos \frac { \pi \qty( m' - m )
 x }{ L } - \cos \frac{\pi\qty( m' + m ) z}{ L }) V(s,z) \dd{z} }_{I_1} \, \times \\
  \underbrace {\int_0^{s_{\mkern-2mu\mathrlap{ f}}} \qty(\cos \frac{\pi(n' -n)s}{s_f} - \cos \frac{\pi \qty( n' + n ) s } { s_{ f }}) \dd{s}}_{I'_1}{} \cdot C_{n,m} + \frac { 1 } { 4 } \sum\limits_{\substack{ n =1 \\ m = 1 }} ^ { N _ { n }, N _ { m } } \int _ {0}^ {s_{\mkern-2mu\mathrlap{ f}}} \qty( \cos \frac {\pi \left( n' - n \right) s} {s_{f}} - \cos \frac{\pi \left( n' + n \right)s} {s _{f}})\dd{s} \times \\
\int_{0}^{L} \left[\cos \frac{\pi \left(m' - m \right) x } {L} - \cos \frac{\pi \left( m' + m \right)z} {L} \right] V (s,z) \dd{z}\cdot C_{n,m}=0
\end{aligned}
\end{medsize}
\end{equation}
\bigskip

\begin{equation}
\begin{medsize}
\begin{multlined}
 \frac{1}{4}\sum_{\substack{n = 1 \\ m = 1}}^{N_{m}, N _{m}}
 \qty(\frac{\pi^{2} n^{2}}{ s_{f}^{2}} + \frac{\pi^{2} m^{2} } {L^{2}} - \tilde{ E })
 \underbrace {\int_0^L \qty( \cos \frac { \pi \qty( m' - m )
 x }{ L } - \cos \frac{\pi\qty( m' + m ) z}{ L }) V(s,z) \dd{z} }_{I_1} \, \times \\
  \underbrace {\int_0^{s_{\mkern-2mu\mathrlap{ f}}} \qty(\cos \frac{\pi(n' -n)s}{s_f} - \cos \frac{\pi \qty( n' + n ) s } { s_{ f }}) \dd{s}}_{I'_1}{} \cdot C_{n,m} + \frac { 1 } { 4 } \sum\limits_{\substack{ n =1 \\ m = 1 }} ^ { N _ { n }, N _ { m } } \int _ {0}^ {s_{\mkern-2mu\mathrlap{ f}}} \qty( \cos \frac {\pi \left( n' - n \right) s} {s_{f}} - \cos \frac{\pi \left( n' + n \right)s} {s _{f}})\dd{s} \times \\
\int_{0}^{L} \left[\cos \frac{\pi \left(m' - m \right) x } {L} - \cos \frac{\pi \left( m' + m \right)z} {L} \right] V (s,z) \dd{z}\cdot C_{n,m}=0
\end{multlined}
 \end{medsize}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]